# What contradictions would result from a violation of Newton's third law (every action has an equal and opposite reaction)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conservation-laws

Let's imagine we have access to a propulsion technology which can move an object, e.g. a space vessel, in one direction without moving anything (such as reaction mass) in the opposite direction. This is, of course, not possible.

I am interested in what contradictions would result from such a technology. We would be able to accelerate in one direction without causing anything else to accelerate in the opposite direction. This violates conservation of momentum.

However, are there any direct contradictions we can show, forming a proof by contradiction of Newton's third law? What plainly impossible things, or contradictions in terms, can arise if something can accelerate without throwing something else in the other direction?

In terms of relativity, accelerating in one direction constitutes a boost. Does relativity have any problems with a object boosting in one direction without reaction? I don't think so, since the reaction mass a craft ejects in order to accelerate does not get boosted as an object, it just disperses (perhaps its individual particles are boosted).

Comment: if that would half the required energy to get something to a particular velocity, thats pretty big.

Comment: Magnetism can violate Newton's third law. 
Consider two charged particles (A and B), with A moving normally to the vector between A and B, and B moving directly towards A, in a 'T' formation. Then B will experience a force from A, but A will not experience a force from B.

Comment: You can't reach logical contradictions by removing an assumption from a logically consistent theory. Only by adding an assumption that is incompatible.

Comment: Myles_H, I don't see how that could possibly be true, because the situation you describe is symmetrical.  If you take B's point of view, the picture is the same as from A's point of view. Furthermore, in most (perhaps all) situations in EM, it is the EM field and the charged object that are the action-reaction pair.

Comment: @RC_23 EM field is not part of an action-reaction pair, because it is not a body, there is no reaction force acting on the EM field. Conservation of momentum holds, but in a different manner, not describable by action-reaction forces.

Answer (score 0):

"Forming a proof by contradiction"

If you mean a logical proof or a mathematical proof then you would first need to state your axioms. If the axioms are Newton's 1st law and 2nd law then the answer is no, there is no logical deduction which will lead to Newton's 3rd law, and therefore no contradiction if one asserts the negation of Newton's 3rd law. This, I emphasize, is a purely mathematical and logical statement.

In physical terms, there are strong reasons to put forward Newton's 3rd law even in the absence of empirical tests. This is because of all the very odd physical phenomena which would be possible if the 3rd law did not hold. A good way to get to grips with this is the method of Lagrangian mechanics. I am guessing you are not familiar with this method. The basic idea is that physical laws describing an isolated system ought not to depend on where the system is located relative to other things, because if they did then that implies the system was not isolated after all. From this we deduce that potential energy functions, for example, only depend on relative positions, not absolute positions. Force is then obtained from gradient of potential energy and Newton's 3rd law follows. Neat, huh?

Here's a little more detail.

The interaction energy arising from some sort of physical interaction between bodies A and B depends on how far they are apart. For illustration, let's suppose the energy goes down as the inverse of the separation:
$$
V = \frac{\alpha}{ | {\bf r}_B - {\bf r}_A | }
$$
where $\alpha$ is some constant.
We can always align our coordinate $x$-axis with the vector $ {\bf r}_B - {\bf r}_A$, and then we have
$$
V = \frac{\alpha}{x_B - x_A}.
$$

Now the force on B is given by the slope of this potential energy as a function of $x_B$, with $x_A$ held constant:
$$
f_B = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_B} = - \frac{\alpha}{( x_B - x_A)^2}
$$
and the force on A is given by the slope of the potential energy as a function of $x_A$, with $x_B$ held constant:
$$
f_A = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_A} = \frac{\alpha}{( x_B - x_A)^2}.
$$
Hence $f_B = - f_A$.

A similar proof holds for any function $V$ which depends only on the separation $|{\bf r}_B - {\bf r}_A|$.

Answer (score 0):

None, because we already know Newton's third law is not obeyed e.g. in EM interactions. If the engine works by shining strong light in one direction, Newton's 3rd law is not obeyed, because there is no other body (other than the rocket) which would experience opposite force of equal magnitude.

Momentum is conserved though, because light carries momentum. But this light is not a body, the engine does not act with force on it, and it need not carry any mass. Thus momentum conservation in this case is not captured/described by Newton's 3rd law. It is described by the law of local conservation of momentum, which can be derived from Maxwell's equations and the Lorentz force formula.